# Is there a function $f\in L_{1}[0,1]$ but $ \frac{d}{dx}\Big(\int_{0}^{x}\frac{f(s)}{(x-s)^{\alpha}}ds\Big)\not\in L_{1}[0,1]? $

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, fractional-calculus

Let $\alpha\in (0,1).$ For a given $f\in L_{1}[0,1]$ consider
$$
\phi(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{f(s)}{(x-s)^{\alpha}}ds, \,\,\,\,\,x\in [0,1].
$$
It is clear that if $\phi\in AC[0,1]$ then $\phi$ is differentiable a.e. and $\phi'\in L_{1}[0,1].$
However, there is a function $f\in L_{1}[0,1]$ such that  $\phi\not\in AC[0,1].$ I am interested in the following question. Is there a function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow R$ such that $f\in L_{1}[0,1]$ but
$\phi'\not\in L_{1}[0,1]?$

Comment: What is $AC[0,1]$ ?

Comment: @Brozovic The space of [absolutely continuous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Absolute_continuity_of_functions).

Comment: @Brozovic to add to the above user's comment: they are, in a sense, the exact set of functions for which the fundamental theorem of calculus holds.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int_{0}^{x}\frac{f(s)}{(x-s)^{\alpha}}ds=\Gamma(1-\alpha)\frac{d^{(\alpha-1)}}{dx^{(\alpha-1)}}f(x)$$
$\Gamma$ is the Gamma function.

$\frac{d^\nu}{dx^\nu}$ denotes the fractionnal derivative of non-integer degree $\nu$ or the fractionnal antiderivative of non-integer degree $-\nu$.

Thus this question is related to fractional calculus : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus

There is an extensive literature about fractional calculus. At lower level, an article for the general public : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14686539/The-Fractional-Derivation-La-derivation-fractionnaire

Also you can find a wide documentation about the above intgral referenced as Riemann-Liouville integral and/or Riemann-Liouville's transform.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this really answers the question since it merely restates the problem which is of a functional analysis nature.

Comment: @JJacquelin. Thank you very much for your suggestion. Indeed, this question is related to Fractional Calculus. I was reading this [article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/1687-2770-2013-23). In Lemma 3.2 (H2), it is said that if  $f\in L_{1}[0,1]$ and $\alpha\in (0,1)$ then $(I^{\alpha}D^{\alpha}f)(x)=f(x)-\frac{(I^{1-\alpha}f)(0)}{\Gamma (\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}$ for almost all $x\in [0,1]$ where $I^{\alpha}$ and $D^{\alpha}$ Riemann-Liouville integral and derivative respectively.

Comment: A question came out, what will heppen if  $D^{\alpha}f\not\in L_{1}[0,1]$ because  $I^{\alpha}$  might not be defined out of  $L_{1}[0,1].$ The [book](https://www.elsevier.com/books/theory-and-applications-of-fractional-differential-equations/kilbas/978-0-444-51832-3) was cited for proof of this lemma (see p.75).

Comment: I have seen this book and found out that this lemma is true for all $\alpha>0$ provided that $I^{n-\alpha}f\in AC [0,1]$ where $n=[\alpha]+1.$ But in particular case $\alpha\in(0,1)$ the asumption $I^{1-\alpha}f\in AC [0,1]$ is not mentioned.

Comment: I would like to know whether the assumption $I^{1-\alpha}f\in AC [0,1]$ is still required for $\alpha\in (0,1)$ or not. If  requred I would like to find a function $f\in L_{1}[0,1]$   such that $(I^{\alpha}D^{\alpha}f)(x)\neq f(x)-\frac{(I^{1-\alpha}f)(0)}{\Gamma (\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}.$

Comment: @MIYY. OK. All this was not said in the querstion. Sorry, that is why I gave an unuseful information. Bytheway his problem is circumvent with the Caputo fractional derivative.